# Transformation array to nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I try to convert some data into a javascript object. The data looks like this:

```
data = [["a","a","a","value1"],
["a","a","b","value2"],
["a","b","value3"],
["a","c","a","value4"]]
```

What I want to get is:

```
a = {
    "a":{
        "a":"value1",
        "b":"value2"
        },
    "b":"value3",
    "c":{
        "a":"value4"
    }
}
```

Since the amount of nested attributes varies I do not know how to do this transformation.

Comment: You will most likely not get a complete solution for your question. However, I would solve this by using recursion. Pass a portion of the data to a function which processes the first string in the array and passes the rest of the array to itself, until there is only one string left.

Comment: Yes, actually this is a good idea I should have come up by myself. I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be the function you're looking for:

```
function addItemToObject(dict, path){
  if (path.length == 2){
    dict[path[0]] = path[1];
  } else {
    key = path.shift()
    if (! dict[key]) {
      dict[key] = {};
    }
    addItemToObject(dict[key], path);
  }
  return dict;
}

var result = data.reduce(addItemToObject,{});
```

The function `addItemToObject` is a recursive function which creates the depth and inserts the value.

This is applied to everything in data using reduce;

Answer (score 0):

## Here's a solution using Ramda.js

```js
const data = [
  ["a","a","a","value1"],
  ["a","a","b","value2"],
  ["a","b","value3"],
  ["a","c","a","value4"]
]

const transformData =
  R.pipe(
    R.map(R.juxt([R.init, R.last])),
    R.reduce(
      (obj, [path, value]) =>
        R.assocPath(path, value, obj),
      {},
    ),
  )

console.log(transformData(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't get your desired solution as there are 4 blocks of data but only 3 properties in the final object.

However, this is how you can iterate through an array and its child arrays:

```
var data = [["a","a","a","value1"],
["a","a","b","value2"],
["a","b","value3"],
["a","c","a","value4"]];

//Store your results in here
var result = {};

//Iterate each block of data in the initial array
data.forEach(function(block){

    //block will refer to an array

    //repeat with the child array
    block.forEach(function(item){
        //item will point to an actual item in the child array
    });

});
```

[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will call a provided function on each item within an array.